# Why my list is not being converted to a float

Tags: python

I have the list of [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5].

```
def calc_mean(arglist):
    return sum(arglist)/len(arglist)

print(calc_mean([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]))
```

I have another list, `strlist = ['0.5','1.5','2.5','3.5']` and I need to convert the elements in it to floats and then calculate the average but I'm getting the error:

`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str')` because the line return sum(arglist)/len(arglist) is working with integers and strlist is a string why strlist isn't being converted to a float and it's being treated as a str even though I converted it using [float(i) if '.' in i else int(i) for i in strlist]

```
def str2float(strlist):
   flist = [float(i) if '.' in i else int(i) for i in strlist] 
   return flist

strlist =  ['0.5','1.5','2.5','3.5']
print(str2float(strlist))
print(calc_mean(strlist))
```

Comment: You need to do `print(calc_mean(str2float(strlist)))`, since `str2float` returns the result.

Comment: `str2float` does not change its input-it returns a new list that you print and discard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> print(calc_mean(strlist))
> ```

As noted in comments, you have not converted `strlist` before passing it to `calc_mean`.

```
print(calc_mean(str2float(strlist)))
```

Comment: Oh, I see the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [@craigb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20236884/craigb) and [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261315/chris), you have to call the conversion function first and then the averaging function.

```py
print(calc_mean(str2float(strlist)))
```

---

If you want to rewrite the code so that you simply automate this control, you can do it in several ways, for example:

```py
def calc_mean(arglist):
    try:
        return sum(arglist) / len(arglist)
    except TypeError:
        recasted_list = str2float(arglist)
        return sum(recasted_list) / len(recasted_list)
```

Also, I suggest rewriting the recast function in a simpler and robust way like this:

```py
def str2float(strlist):
    return [float(i) for i in strlist]
```

It can be done in many other ways of course, but it always depends on the extent of the upstream problem you want to solve.